# Calculate Code density and Memory traffic for Assembly code

Tags: assembly, memory

We assume that the values of the variables A, B, C, D, F are located in the central memory of the computer. All variables are 4 byte integers. Opcodes are 1 byte, except push/pop operations which are 2 bits. Memory addressing is 16 bits and register addressing is 5 bits. Calculate  code density and memory traffic for the following code :

a)

```
    PUSH D
    PUSH B
    PUSH A
    ADD
    PUSH C
    MUL
    DIV
    POP F
```

b)

```
    LOAD A
    ADD B
    STORE T
    LOAD C
    DIV D
    MUL T
    STORE F
```

For case , i've made some calculations

```
    Code Density for A)  = number of push/pop* 2bit + number.ALU instructions * 8 bit +  
    number of push/pop * 16 bit  = 5*2+ 3*8 + 5 *16 = 10+24+80=114 bit

    Code density for B) = Total nuber of instructions * 8bit + number of Load/Store * 16 bit  
                        = 7*8 + 4*16 =56+64 =120 bit

    Memorty traffic Case A = ?????
    Memory Traffic Case B = ????
```

I don't know if these calculations are ok , and what about Memory traffic ?

Comment: Be careful not to mix bit and byte terms together, convert one to the other in order to combine.

Comment: @ErikEidt in calculations are all converted to bits

Comment: *except push/pop operations which are 2 bits* - That seems unlikely.  Did you mean 2 *bytes*?  Or is that not including the operand?  So `push reg` is 7 bits, not a whole byte?  Machine code for this ISA is a bitstream, like iAPX_432? 
 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432#Instruction_format)